# Incorrect Colors in Jetpack Compose Preview and Physical Device

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, material-components-android

I'm facing an issue with colors in my Jetpack Compose app. Both in the Android Studio Preview and on my physical device (Samsung SM-G780G - Android 13.0), the colors are incorrect. In the Preview, the colors do not match the ones I defined, and on the physical device, the colors also do not match, appearing to be the default Material Design colors.

Here is my files.
Color file

```kotlin
package com.asset.login_signup_recover.screens.theme

import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color

val Purple80 = Color(0xFFD0BCFF)
val PurpleGrey80 = Color(0xFFCCC2DC)
val Pink80 = Color(0xFFEFB8C8)

val Purple40 = Color(0xFF6650a4)
val PurpleGrey40 = Color(0xFF625b71)
val Pink40 = Color(0xFF7D5260)

val BrightOrange = Color(0xFFFF8A65)
val MediumOrange = Color(0xFFFFA000)
val DarkOrange = Color(0xFFF57C00)
```

And here's my theme file where I made some color modifications:

```kotlin
package com.asset.login_signup_recover.screens.theme


private val DarkColorScheme = darkColorScheme(
    primary = BrightOrange,
    primaryContainer = BrightOrange,
    secondary = DarkOrange
)

private val LightColorScheme = lightColorScheme(
    primary = BrightOrange,
    primaryContainer = BrightOrange,
    secondary = DarkOrange
)

@Composable
fun AppTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    dynamicColor: Boolean = false,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colorScheme = when {
        dynamicColor && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S -> {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
        }

        darkTheme -> DarkColorScheme
        else -> LightColorScheme
    }
    val view = LocalView.current
    if (!view.isInEditMode) {
        SideEffect {
            val window = (view.context as Activity).window
            window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.primary.toArgb()
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = darkTheme
        }
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
    )
}
```

The problem persists both in the Preview and on the physical device. The only configuration that generates the correct colors is when dynamicColor is set to false on the device with API 34, indicating that the issue may be related to default Jetpack Compose settings. How can I ensure that the colors are always orange, regardless of the settings, in both the Preview and on the physical device?

Example image of the problem:
Emulator API 34

[image: Emulator API 34]

Same screen on Android Studio Preview & Emulator

[image]

When I set dynamicColors to false emulator device works ( did not tested on physical atm but may be working too )

[image]

I expected these custom colors to appear correctly both in the Android Studio Preview and on my physical device.

Comment: The dynamic colors is a new feature in recent android versions you will have to define colors for it or just disable it if you need your app to stay always orange

Comment: so I need to remove this part? for preview work?